# View is calling viewDidLoad() when navigating back

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When the user selects a cell in the collection view, it pushes to a new view controller for that cell.

The problem is that when the user swipes back, the collection view controller runs viewDidLoad() instead of viewDidAppear(). This causes the whole collection view to reload and go back up to the top (first cell) and the user has to scroll all the way back down to get to where they were before.

Does anyone know why this is happening??

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let reuseIdentifier = "PostCell"

var post: [Post] = [Post]()

var imageURLs: [URL] = [URL]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.91, green: 0.91, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1.00)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    //setupHorizontalBar()
    setupCollectionView()

    // Get all of the posts
    loadPosts()

    print("loaded")

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    print("appeared")
    collectionView.index
}

func setupCollectionView() {

    if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }

}

func loadPosts() {
    postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for eachPost in snapshot.value as! [String: Any] {
            let dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [eachPost.key: eachPost.value]
            let post = Post(postDictionary: dict)
            print(post)
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    //cell.backgroundColor = .brown
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = post.name
    let details = "\n\(post.address!)\n\n\(post.time!) \(post.date!)"
    cell.postDetailTextView.text = details
    if let imageURL = post.image {

        print(imageURL)

        cell.postImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL))
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let height = (self.view.frame.width - 20) * 9 / 16
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: height + 5 + 140)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

When `didSelectItemAt` is called, I want the navigation controller to push to another view controller for the cell selected.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
    let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}

}
```

Comment: The thing you need to show is is the code on the detail view controller that handles the back button. Have you connected the back button to a push segue by any chance? And are you showing a navigation bar with a back button or relying on a swipe gesture for the user to pop the detail view controller?

Comment: @DuncanC The detail view controller is just a blank view controller for now. When you push a view in a navigation controller it supplies a pre-made back button and swipe gesture to navigate back (That is what I am using). I am just confused on why it is calling 'viewDidLoad' and not 'viewDidAppear'.

Comment: I am not sure if it's related, but you override `viewDidAppear` to call `viewDidAppear(true)` on `super`. I think it should pass the `animated` value instead.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs That was a mistake on my part, thanks for finding it! It did not change anything though.

Comment: Ok, that's normal and correct. I answered a question the other day from somebody who implemented a back button that that they linked to a `show` segue. That would cause the exact symptom you describe. As it is, I don't know why you're getting that.

Comment: @DuncanC Do you have any ideas for a workaround? Should I maybe store the selected indexPath and when the user navigates back I should scroll down to the cell with that indexPath?